# Difference of meaning between gerund and verb

Tags: gerunds

"I like your working." Is this sentence correct? If it is, then what is the difference between- "I like your working." and "I like your work."

Comment: It's *possible* to contrive a context where ***I like your working*** (or the equivalent "non-gerund" version *I like **you** working*) would be a "fairly" natural thing to say (with the specific meaning *I like **the fact that** you work*). But for the purposes of most learners it would be better to just say it's "not correct". If you like the ***finished products*** from someone's labour (you like an artist's paintings, for example), the only valid form is ***I like your work***.

Comment: ... If you specifically want to draw attention to the ***process*** rather than the ***end product***, you might say something like *I like **the way** [that] you work.* Note that *I like **your working*** is a "gerund" usage, *I like **you working*** is a continuous verb form, and *I like your **work*** is a noun.